# How to invoke "next track" and "star current track" from my Spotify App?

Tags: spotify, skip

I just started writing a little Spotify App and can't figure out how to invoke the two functions next/star from Javascript. I just need this simple functionality: From within my App (Javascript) call a method that skips the current track and plays the next one (if there is any) OR call a method that "stars" (is this really a verb?) the current song.

Is this [API DOC](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/) the only resource for building my own App? Thanks in advance for any hints on this!

**UPDATE:** Just found out how to SKIP: *sp.trackPlayer.skipToNextTrack();*
Unfortunately, how to "star" a track remains unknown.

**UPDATE 2:** GOT IT! : *models.library.starredPlaylist.add(models.player.track);* – yep that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to star a track is indeed the function you wrote:

```
models.library.starredPlaylist.add(models.player.track);
```

trackPlayer is not a supported object that shouldn't be accessed by developers since it's not versioned properly. This means that it may break in the future when we do updates to the platform bridge.

We recommend only using the documented classes on our developer website.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/

The correct way to skip to the next track is to use:

```
models.player.next()
```